# kubernetes pod affinity `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` pods stuck in pending state

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to use pod affinity to have 2 pods in the same node in gke so when I use `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` pods are never creating and stuck at pending state throwing this error:

> cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added)

and when using `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` pods are never assigned to same node.

Comment: can you provide the node and pods capacity details?

Comment: I would check if the issue is resource-related.
To do so, describe the pods stuck by running the command $ kubectl describe pod name-of-the-pod

Comment: the node capacity is 4 vCPUs, 15 GB memory and the pod I didn't specify resources It was nginx deployment

Comment: Check if the resources (CPU, ephemeral storage, GPU, storage) of the nodes are reaching the maximum. You can find this information in the Console (graphical interface), by clicking on the name of the cluster and then clicking on the name of the node, you will see all the graphs and info displaying there.
If you see that it's needed you can update the resources to add more if necessary.

Comment: @Paula Does the auto scale should kick in, if the resources are not available?